# How does C-3PO know who BB-8 is?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

A lot of people will probably gloss over this fact, but it looks like C-3PO meets BB-8 for the first time in this scene 0:20:

### But how does C-3PO know BB-8's name?

Is there a time where C-3PO meets BB-8 before this and knows his name?

Comment: BB-8 and C3PO have both been working for the Resistance. It's likely they've met before this.

Comment: *"This video contains content from Disney, who has blocked it on Copyright Grounds"*

Comment: @Valorum, can't seem to get the video to work.

Comment: Seems the video is dead again.

Answer (score 5):

Poe Dameron and BB-8 are both members of the Resistance. It seems impossible that Threepio, attaché to the leader of the Resistance, has *not* previously met BB-8, the droid belonging to the Resistance's best pilot.

I don't know if their first meeting has yet been depicted in canon materials, but we have evidence of their meeting prior to *The Force Awakens* in the comic book special *C-3PO: The Phantom Limb* (click to embiggen):

[image: 3PO finds a new red arm to replace a missing one alongside BB-8 and Poe]

[image: 3PO and BB-8 look out of a window aboard a starfighter]

**Transcript of final panel:**

> **BB-8:** Mreet mrrt
>
> **C-3PO:** Yes, Beebee-Ate, I'm fine. I know I'm quiet, you're not the first to say that to me lately.
>
> <sup>*C-3PO: The Phantom Limb* (2016)</sup>

Comment: @KyloRen No, there's no evidence they *haven't* met, and at least one piece of evidence that they *have*. I even re-watched the scene you tried to embed in your question, and there is absolutely no indication that they don't know each other

Comment: So where have they met before then?

Comment: @KyloRen [I don't know if their first meeting has yet been depicted in canon materials, but we have evidence of their meeting prior to The Force Awakens in the comic book special C-3PO: The Phantom Limb](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142578/31051)

Comment: I know they like to spell out droid names for the comics/scripts (Artoo, Threepio, etc. ) But "Beebee-ate", ATE, that just make me laugh.